# Endless scroll using QuiltView in android

Tags: android, gridview, grid-layout

I am using the QuiltView to display the data(Text, images and video) and I also want endless scroll in this.
As much as i understand the QuiltView is basically using the GridLayout not GridView.

Is this correct? 
If QuiltView is using the GridLayout then can I use `OnScrollListener`?

Is there anyone have the example of QuiltView with Endless scroll.